# What happens to the mom in A Bronx Tale

Tags: plot-explanation, a-bronx-tale

In the 1993 movies [A Bronx Tale](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106489/) what happens to [Calogero](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0012645/)'s mom [Rosina](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0044854/). She sort of just dissappears after Calogero turns 17 but you see the dad (Deniro) quite a bit. Does she die? Divorce?

Comment: Seventeen year old Calogero, during an argument with his Father, states that his Mother "Left." In my opinion, she leaves him for being a broke bus driver.

Comment: I literally just scanned the entire script for "mom", "mother", "she", "left" and "Rosina" and found no dialogue that indicates there was any discussion about Rosina leaving.

Comment: She's in the window as they are approaching the building

Comment: She had shut the window after they both walk inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some googleing + IMDB + Wiki, all I could find is that this seems to be an **intentional ambiguity** for the story.  Either that or the writer just didn't think the character was interesting enough to write about after this point.

Answer (score 0):

She didn't go anywhere. She is looking out the window when C and his father are returning home from the funeral parlor. Look real closely. Soon as they go into the building, she goes back inside.

Comment: A screencap of the described scene would be a helpful addition to this answer.